# Access of webpage from CodeNameOne

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to access a web page from CodeNameOne application. Strangely the simulator is throwing errors whereas the application is working fine in andriod mobile.

**Code Snippet:**

> Form loginForm = new Form("LoginNew"); loginForm.setLayout(new
>   BorderLayout()); WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser()
>   browser.setURL("http://mobile.apps-tek.com:8081/apps-webservices");
>   loginForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,browser); loginForm.show();

Error while running in simulator.

```
Attribute 'xmlns' is not supported for tag 'html'.
The tag 'script' is not supported in XHTML-MP 1.0
The tag 'script' is not supported in XHTML-MP 1.0
Attribute 'onload' is not supported for tag 'body'.
Attribute 'name' is not supported for tag 'form'.
The tag 'script' is not supported in XHTML-MP 1.0
The tag 'script' is not supported in XHTML-MP 1.0
The tag 'script' is not supported in XHTML-MP 1.0
Attribute 'onclick' is not supported for tag 'input'.
The tag 'script' is not supported in XHTML-MP 1.0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.scale(JavaSEPort.java:3047)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scale(Image.java:930)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaled(Image.java:900)
    at com.codename1.ui.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread.handleImage(ResourceThreadQueue.java:562)
    at com.codename1.ui.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread.handleImage(ResourceThreadQueue.java:511)
    at com.codename1.ui.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread.access$000(ResourceThreadQueue.java:360)
    at com.codename1.ui.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread$1.run(ResourceThreadQueue.java:479)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1075)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1019)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:925)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
[EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Exception in AppName version 1.0
[EDT] 0:0:0,1 - OS ios
[EDT] 0:0:0,1 - Error java.lang.NullPointerException
[EDT] 0:0:0,1 - Current Form null
[EDT] 0:0:0,1 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.scale(JavaSEPort.java:3047)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scale(Image.java:930)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaled(Image.java:900)
    at com.codename1.ui.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread.handleImage(ResourceThreadQueue.java:562)
    at com.codename1.ui.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread.handleImage(ResourceThreadQueue.java:511)
    at com.codename1.ui.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread.access$000(ResourceThreadQueue.java:360)
    at com.codename1.ui.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread$1.run(ResourceThreadQueue.java:479)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1075)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1019)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:925)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using Java 6 or Java 7 that is configured without Java FX support. When running without Java FX Codename One defaults to the feature phone web browser component which is pretty limited and problematic.

Make sure that the VM used to run Codename One is Java SE 7 and that the additional Java FX libraries are included there.

Comment: It worked!!!!!....I updated the JRE under Run/Debug Settings of the project and was able to run the application in simulator. However the web page was displayed with scrolls. Cant this be avoided?

Comment: The scrollbars are a feature of the desktop browser. On the device you will have standard touch scrolling.